# How to fix "0xC0000005: Access violation reading location" in C++

Tags: c++, cplex

I've been learning how to write optimization programming in c++ recently. I kept receiving the same message once I build my optimization model:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVdMj.png)

Can someone help me or tell me what's going on there? Thanks a lot.

```cpp
#include <ilcplex/ilocplex.h> ILOSTLBEGIN

typedef IloArray<IloNumVarArray> IloNumVarArray2;

int main(int argc, char ∗∗argv) {
  IloEnv env;

  try {
    const char;

    IloInt i, j;
    IloModel mod(env);

    IloNumVarArray2 x(env);
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      x.add(IloNumVarArray(env, 2, 0.0, IloInfinity));
    }

    mod.add(IloMaximize(
        env, 6.5 * x[0][0] + 11 * x[0][1] + 9.75 * x[1][0] + 12.25 * x[1][1] +
                 9.5 * x[1][2] + 4.75 * x[2][0] + 7.75 * x[2][1] +
                 8.5 * x[2][2] + 7.5 * x[3][0] + 8.5 * x[3][1]));
    mod.add(x[0][0] + x[1][0] + x[2][0] + x[3][0] >= 500);
    mod.add(x[0][1] + x[1][1] + x[2][1] + x[3][1] >= 600);
    mod.add(x[0][2] + x[1][2] + x[2][2] + x[3][2] >= 500);

    mod.add(x[0][0] + x[0][1] <= 600);
    mod.add(x[1][0] + x[1][1] + x[1][2] <= 500);
    mod.add(x[2][0] + x[2][1] + x[2][2] <= 300);
    mod.add(x[3][0] + x[3][1] <= 400);

    IloCplex cplex(mod);

    if (!cplex.solve()) {
      env.error() << "Failed to optimize LP." << endl;
      throw(-1);
    }

    IloNumArray vals(env);
    env.out() << "Solution status = " << cplex.getStatus() << endl;
    env.out() << "Solution value = " << cplex.getObjValue() << endl;
    env.out() << "Values = " << vals << endl;

  } catch (IloException &e) {
    cerr << "Error 2" << e << endl;
  } catch (...) {
    cerr << "Error 1" << endl;
  }
  env.end();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I read this code correctly, `x` is only three rows but you access it as `x[3][0]` (the fourth row). Every element of `x` is only two columns yet you access `x[2][2]` (third column).

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: @OP You are using Visual Studio, where the debugging is very easy.  That exception box comes with a call stack.  The call stack would have shown you exactly the line that caused the issue, and all you would need to do is click a button to close out that box and go to the Call Stack window.  Very simple.

Comment: Botje: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Sam and Paul: Thanks for the tips! I use Visual Studio right now, and I got an iloenv.h file once I use the debugger, and the screenshot is added as a link in the problem description. I don't have a clue where the issue reported is located in my model since the line number does not match (I only have less than 50 lines).

Answer (score 1):

Like people in the comments suggested, use a debugger to track down the problem. Even better: compile your program in debug mode. The IloCplex code contains a good number of assertions in the header files that catch common errors. Running your code in debug mode gives this assertion failure:

```
X& IloArray::operator[] (IloInt i) : Out of bounds operation: index superior to size of array
segfault2.bin++: concert/include/ilconcert/iloenv.h:2246: X& IloArray<X>::operator[](IloInt) [with X = IloNumVarArray; IloInt = long int]: Assertion `(i < _impl->getSize()) || (std:: cerr << "X& IloArray::operator[] (IloInt i) : Out of bounds operation: index superior to size of array" << std:: endl, ilo_stop_assert())' failed.
Aborted
```

This clearly shows that you are accessing an array out of its bounds (like one of the comments already suggests). Tracing this back, you can see that the offending line in your code is:

```
mod.add(IloMaximize(
    env, 6.5 * x[0][0] + 11 * x[0][1] + 9.75 * x[1][0] + 12.25 * x[1][1] +
             9.5 * x[1][2] + 4.75 * x[2][0] + 7.75 * x[2][1] +
             8.5 * x[2][2] + 7.5 * x[3][0] + 8.5 * x[3][1]));
```

You are accesing `x[3][*]` although the `x` array has only 3 elements. So only indices 0, 1, 2 are valid for this array. Also, you are accessing `x[*][2]` in some places, although the second dimension of your array is only 2.